# Magnetic field enegy conservation

Tags: electric-circuits, energy-conservation, electrical-resistance, inductance, batteries

I will close the circuit with an inductor across a battery along with a resistor connected in series with battery and inductor, after reaching steady state I will break the circuit. then current in the inductor suddenly becomes zero what happens to the magnetic field energy stored in the inductor.
if current suddenly becomes zero there will be development of infinite potential difference this can be used to produce heavy voltage.

Comment: And you have just discovered the principle of an ignition coil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've observed, when the current in an inductor is suddenly interrupted, the voltage on the inductor could become very high (V=-L*di/dt) as the inductor attempts to maintain the current.

This voltage will be added to the battery voltage and most of it will be applied to the switch or whatever device is used to break the flow of the current.

If it is a mechanical switch, the air in the gap between the parting contacts will ionize and the current will continue to flow, forming an arc. If it is a solid state switch (like a transistor), it could break down or, alternatively, an arc could jump between its leads.

As the current flows through the switching device and through other resistive elements in the circuit, it will cause power dissipation (I^2*R). This is where most of the energy stored on the inductor, LI^2/2, will be burned.

To prevent the destruction of switching devices, a diode is often installed in parallel with an inductor. During normal operation, the diode is reverse biased and does not affect the functionality of the circuit, but when the circuit is opened, the voltage, generated on the inductor, turns the diode on and the inductor current continues to flow in a loop formed by the inductor and the diode.

In this case, most of the magnetic field energy is burned on the diode, but since the voltage drop on the forward biased diode is relatively small (on the order of 0.4-0.8 volts), the power dissipation will be relatively low and will be spread over longer period of time, without causing any damage.

Adding, per your suggestion in the comments, that, at low energy levels, the energy of the magnetic field could be dissipated through the oscillations, with the current bouncing back and forth without crossing the open switch.

Comment: what if there no medium i.e vaccum around the disconnected part

Comment: Field emission or something like that.

Comment: what do you mean by that

Comment: I think current continues for some time in the circuit and develops charge at the ends on conductor and current develops again in opposite direction due to potential difference caused by the develoded charge performing LC oscilalations and dissipates energy by heating due to current.i..e conductor acts as a capacitor

Comment: I meant that, when a field is very strong, the electrons could, in theory, jump through a gap between two conductors without air ionization and initiate an arc, which may involve metal atoms.

Comment: I can see the oscillations as well, but for that to happen, the switch would have to withstand very high voltage, since all mag field energy LI^2/2 would have to turn into the field energy CV^2/2. For 1A, 100mH, 10pF circuit, that would mean 100kV or something like that.